# Excel VBA - rename a file into same directory by adding contents of a cell into first space in old file name

Tags: excel, vba

So far have this code, where: E1 = path to current folder; H = file name:

```
Set fso = CreateObject(""Scripting.FileSystemObject"") 
FileSource = ""Range("E1") & Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value"" 'original
FileDest = ""Range("E1") & Range("H" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value"" 'new
fso.copyfile FileSource, FileDest, True 
If (fso.fileexists(FileDest)) Then 
fso.deletefile FileSource, True 
End If
```

Original file name has at least one space in it - looks something like this "First Second Third.pdf".  I'd want for new file name to place contents of cell J1 into new file name like so "First -contents of cell J1- Second Third.pdf"

**10.8.18 - to clarify -** I have a list of file names in column A6 down, and path to folder which contains those files in A3. I am trying to accomplish renaming of those files by adding contents of a cell J1 into first space in old file name. And to do that for just one file at a time, one in active row.

Answer (score 1):

Those quotes aren't necessary; in fact they are hindering the worksheet cell read.

Replace should be able to change the first space to whatever is in the J1 cell.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
FileSource = Range("E1") & Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value 'original
FileDest = Range("E1") & Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value 'new
fso.copyfile FileSource, replace(FileDest, chr(32), range("J1").value, 1, 1), True 
If (fso.fileexists(FileDest)) Then 
    fso.deletefile FileSource, True 
End If
```

Comment: Hi, Excel "gives Run-time error'76': Path not found" on this line `fso.copyfile FileSource, Replace(FileDest, Chr(32), " - " & Range("L1").Value & " - ", 1, 1), True`.  I have modified your original solution a bit, but not materially to explain this error, I adjusted it to my current actual locations of path and file name: E1 replaced with A3, H with A and J1 with L1.  Also added `" - " & Range("L1").Value & " - "` to wrap contents with spaces and dashes in new file name

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `InStr` function to find the location of the first space. Then use `Left` and `Right` to build your new string.

Example: In cell `J1` I placed the text `Contents of J1`. Below is the code and outputs from each variable I used where `String2` is your requested output

```
Dim String1 As String 'Original String
Dim Space1 As Integer 'First Space Location
Dim String2 As String 'Final String
Dim Insert As String 'Contents of J1

String1 = ThisWorkbook.Name
Space1 = InStr(String1, " ")
Insert = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Max").Range("J1")
String2 = Left(myString, Space1) & Insert & " " & Right(String1, Len(String1) - Space1)
```

[image]

Comment: InStr is vba's search.

Comment: @Jeeped I thought that returned a boolean result? Or is it both?

Comment: some people use it incorrectly as a boolean without conversion. InStr returns the position of the substr within the string. False is zero and anything that is not false is true so generally speaking, it works without wrapping a cbool conversion around it. However if you try to use two InStr with And you are destined for trouble 'cause 1 And 3 is true but 2 And 4 is false.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped! I was not aware about all the options of `InStr`, I've only seen it be used for boolean tests. Just read about it on Microsoft and updated my solution

Comment: @urdearboy - to clarify - I have a list of file names in column A6 down, and path to folder which contains those files in A3.  I am trying to accomplish renaming of those files by adding contents of a cell J1 into first space in old file name. And to do that for just one file at a time, one in active row. Can you help?